# Date and month and year comparison in VB.net - Sql Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, vb.net

I have data in today date (20/10/2016) in Sql Server, I need to show the data after it completed 3 months (20/02/2017) how to validate using select query

Comment: Simply use a WHERE-condition where you add three months to today: `dateadd` & `getdate`

Comment: Using the dateadd function

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
SELECT DATEADD(MONTH, 3, yourfield), yourfield
FROM yourtable
```

I put two fields in your query so you'll show the current date and the future date (after 3 months)

Answer (score 1):

I think you want this (20/2/2017) as your output result.

then try following select query which gives you the date after 3 months of current date.

```
select dateadd(m,4,getdate())
```

adding 4 in month will give you the month after 3 month of current date.

Answer (score 0):

getdate() includes the time. So if he checks at an earlier time, although with the same date, query will return incorrect results. You can use:

```
select cast( floor( cast( dateadd( m, 4, getdate() ) as float ) ) as datetime ) newdate
```

to convert the result to a date with a time of 00:00:00

or if it is from a column in your table:

```
select cast( floor( cast( dateadd( m, 4, yourdatecolumn ) as float ) ) as datetime ) newdate 
from yourtable
```